# NodeJs how to compress uint8array in background

Tags: multithreading, node.js, zip, compression, web-worker

I have a multiuser application using node.js and I want to compress a large uint8array and store it after compression (so there are no realtime requirements).

As the compression is probably blocking and might take time I would like to do this in a background thread. What would be the best way to do this? (example code would be nice as I have had some problems using external libary with webworker).

Data is very repetitive so simple deflate-like compression is probably good enough.

Comment: Isn't node.js single threaded?

Comment: There are pure thread implementations (https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) and webworker implementations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) and lots of more based on these.

Comment: Sorry I'm not an node.js developer, comes only to mind as I read your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `zlib` module for that. It includes async functions which delegate to thread pool under the hood. The only problem is that it works with `Buffer`s, not typed arrays.  There is no good way to convert typed arrays or array buffers into node buffers, so you should consider using buffers for storing binary data.

Comment: Converting data to buffers is currently not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't transfer binary data from typed arrays to buffers without byte-by-byte copying. The only option is to reimplement needed functionality in C++.

Comment: That's what I thought. I think I'll just find some simple zlib implementation and create the webworker based on that. Thanks for comment anyway.

Comment: Not sure it's possible, all webworker style libs I saw don't have access to node apis, such as `require`, only pure js.

Comment: Yup it seems that way which is shame. But copying code (deflate shouldn't be that hard) should solve the trick.